# I'd like to use a sum function for the named range in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to use sum function for specific range I definded in google script.

I typed as following, but second code does not work.

var myRange = mySheet.getRange(6,6,4,1);

mySheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=SUM(myRange)' )

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumofrange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  Logger.log(sh.getRange("A2:A5").getValues().flat().reduce((a,c,i) => {a += c; return a;},0));
}
```